# Expectation of correlated variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, correlation

I wish to evaluate synbolically the correlation between two random variables $s_1,s_2$. They are defined by transforming four normal independent variables:
$$s_1=(\eta_1+\rho\eta_2)^3+\alpha\eta_3\\ s_2=(\eta_1+\rho\eta_2)^3+\alpha\eta_4$$with $$\eta_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i)\\
\rho,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$

For readability purposes, I wrote my code with many symbols. Thus, I post here a screenshot

[image: Code]

The two evaluations shown here are indeed correct. However, if I try to compute the correlation $E[s_1,s_2]$ as following

`Expectation[s1*s2,{s1\[Distributed]S1,s2\[Distributed]S2}]`

it gets stuck evaluating it.

## EDIT

Strange fact, if I define directly the expectation $E[s_1,s_2]$ through the "base" random variables $\eta_i$, the evaluation does not fail.

[image: CrossCorrelation]

Any explanation for the different behaviour, depending on the definition?

Comment: Read this post https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/8822 if you want a better formatting for yuor post.

Comment: You have an error in your edit:  you've switched $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ in the second term (or the error is in the original post).

Comment: Your code doesn't seem consistent in that sometimes there are subscripts and sometimes not.  Also when you use `Expectation[s1*s2,{s1\[Distributed]S1,s2\[Distributed]S2}]`, the documentation states that you are assuming `S1` and `S2` are independent (which they are not).  (This is not at all to say there aren't quirks when using `TransformedDistribution`.)

Comment: $\text{Cov}(S_1,S_2) = 15 \left(\sigma _1^2 + \rho ^2 \sigma _2^2\right)^3$

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

It's not different behavior.  When you use

```
Expectation[s1*s2,{s1\[Distributed]S1,s2\[Distributed]S2}]
```

the documentation states that you are assuming that `s1` and `s2` are independent (which they are not).

In addition you've previously defined `s1` and `s2` as "constants" in that `Expectation` doesn't know about $\eta1$, $\eta2$, $\eta3$, and $\eta4$ being random variables so you get the wrong answer even if s1 and s2 were independent:

```
(α η4 + (η2 + η1 ρ)^3) (α η3 + (η1 + η2 ρ)^3)
```

If `s1` and `s2` were independent you'd want $E(s1 * s2) = E(s1)*E(s2)$.  You would want to use some previously undefined variables:

```
Expectation[x1 x2, {x1 \[Distributed] S1, x2 \[Distributed] S2}]
```

which gives you 0 in this case (and both means for `S1` and `S2` are zero).